# Sort by has wrong icon in DataGridPro

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, icons, mui-datatable

In the documentation, it seems that the sort icons are reversed.
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/sorting/

[Sort by asc in documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTPBD.png)
[Sort by desc in documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja2oZ.png)

When sorting by ascending, the arrow icon goes from bottom to top when it should be top to bottom.
When sorting by descending, the arrow icon goes from top to bottom when it should be from bottom to top.

[Universal icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7YcC.png)

Is this a mistake? Is it possible to change the direction?

Thank you for your help !

I've found several topics that talk about changing the color or the icon, but I'd just like to change the direction of the existing one and understand why it's not the right way round.